# Devise not calling overridden function - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to store a list of permissions within a session variable after a user signs up or logs in to their account. The following code only works when a user logs into a currently saved account. What method do I need to override to save the permissions when the account is created via sign up?

```
class UserSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  after_action :after_login, :only => :create

  def after_login
      session[:permissions] = current_user.list_permissions
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 after_action :after_signup, :only => :create

  def after_signup
   ## your data permissions
end
```

It might be necessary to inject via resource. In this case try (i commented it out quickly, just in case you wondering whats going on):

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


  def create
## GET THE SIGN UP DATA
    super do |resource|
##CHECK IF DATA IS VALID
      if params[:your_data]
##SET THE RESOURCE TO THE DATA
        resource.your_data = params[:your_data]
##CHECK (IF NECESSARY) DATA TO TYPE
        if resource.you == 2
## SAVE IT
          resource.save_with_your_data
## SAVE WITH STANDARD SETTINGS
        else
          resource.save
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I was able to use the after_sign_up def to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What method do I need to override to save the permissions when the account is created via sign up?

It seems like you want to store this information in the database when the user is created. Remember that `current_user` will give you the entire database record in the object, and then you can do whatever you need with it. I wouldn't recommend messing the session directly, instead, work with the current_user object that Devise provides.